# JQuery Modal Box On PHP else die

Tags: php, jquery

Just wondering if there is a way to include a JQuery modal box/popup in the event of a PHP else die statement, e.g: `else die("Invalid");`.

So rather than the  output `Invalid` displaying on the page, the else die triggers a JQuery modal popup box that contains the output `Invalid`.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and leverage `throw new Exception()` along with `try/catch` statements.

Answer (score 0):

First better use exit() not die :) it's the standard.

You can write

```
else { exit("<script>alert('s');</script>"); }
```

Inside it you can write in your script. 
It will run! But if you want jquery you must be sure that it has been loaded before this exit line. After it nothing more will be send to user browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by simply tracking the success output from php

```
<?php
if($logged) {
 echo "success";
} else {
 die("Sorry incorrect login information");
}
?>
```

and you can track it with jquery

```
$(#form).on("submit",function() {
var inputs = $(this).serialize();
var ulr = $(this).attr("action");
$.post(url, inputs, function(data) {
 if(data !="success") {
//display UI dialog or alert with data

} else {
//proceed
}
});
});
```